# How to trigger onSubmitted on a Flutter for web TextField

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a small flutter app for the web and am showing a TextField.

I now need a callback like onSubmitted whenever the user either leaves the TextField (focus loss) or presses the Enter key. Right now I can't make any callback happen at all.

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Name',
  ),
  controller: TextEditingController(text: event.name),
  onEditingComplete: () { print("editing complete"); },
  onSubmitted: (String value) { print("submitted\n"); },
  maxLines: 1,
),
```

Comment: Maybe try onchanged

Comment: I tried this code and it works, the problem might be in another part of the app. Could you put the some extra code where you are using this TextField?

Comment: @0x58 onchanged fires on every keystroke, except on "Enter" or Focus loss. But I want to know when the user is done editing so I can save the new value.

Comment: @PabloBarrera are you running the sample on the web or in Android / iOS?

Comment: I tried on Android, but with a physical device. Maybe in an emulator doesn't work according to this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19027. But I posted an answer with a workaround for web.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me on Flutter Web

```
            TextField(
              controller: _passwordController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Password',
              ),
              obscureText: true,
              onSubmitted: (value) {
                _loginPresenter.login(
                    _usernameController.text, _passwordController.text);
              },
            ),
```

Note the definition of `onSubmitted`. When the user presses the Enter key on flutter web, the `loginPresenter.login` method will be called.

Comment: Marking this as the new solution now, since the bug in flutter mentioned above was fixed some time ago and we no longer need the workaround.

Comment: This works for my desktop app but when I use the web app on a mobile device I can't trigger `onSubmitted`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an issue:
[[web]: TextField onSubmitted is not triggered when pressing enter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35435)

This is a workaround mentioned in the link:

```
    body: RawKeyboardListener(
      focusNode: focusNode,
      onKey: (event) {
        if (event is RawKeyUpEvent && event.data is RawKeyEventDataAndroid) {
          var data = event.data as RawKeyEventDataAndroid;
          if (data.keyCode == 13) {
            debugPrint('onSubmitted');
          }
        }
      },
      child: TextField(),
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks for digging this up! I just also found this bug. But I have trouble integrating the workaround. I managed to get the event handler now, but how would I now access the text value of the child? See also my comment on the bug report.

Comment: You should have a controller attached to the TextField, then you can access to the text with controller.text

Comment: As you can see in the sample I posted I do have a controller attached, but I might be just also missing how to structure a flutter program. How would I access the controller from the event handler?

Comment: You should put the controller into a variable and then use that variable to attach the controller to the TextField and to get the text value from somewhere. You could initialize the controller on the initState()

Comment: Ok thanks, I figured it out. Even though it adds quite a bit of boiler plate code. Hope it gets fixed soon :-(

Comment: @Fabian what was your final code snippet in the end? I am trying to get android enter button to work in flutter web

Answer (score 1):

Also removing the `maxLines: 1` seems to get the onsubmitted to work.[Faced the same issue on mobile]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this create a methode where you make a condition on your TextEditingController and based on that you can submite on your TextField.

- First

```
   final entredTitle = titleController.text;
   final entredAmount = double.parse(amountController.text);
   if (entredTitle.isEmpty || entredAmount <= 0 ){
     return ;
   }
   widget.addTx(entredTitle,entredAmount);
   Navigator.of(context).pop();
 }
```

- Second

```
 TextField(
                      decoration:  InputDecoration(labelText: 'Amount'),
                      controller: amountController,
                      onSubmitted: (_) => submitData(),
                    ),
```